# Deriving integer solutions to quadratic equation without solving quadratic congruence

Tags: number-theory, quadratics, euclidean-algorithm, quadratic-programming

I want to generate positive integer solutions of $x$ to the equation:

$x^2-x-aT=0$

where a is an integer $>$ 0 and T is a very large positive number.

I noticed that when plugging this into wolfram alpha is looks like it was formulating the equation in the form:

$x^2-x≡0 (mod T)$

And then solving this quadratic congruence to get the equations to generate all integer solutions to my equation.

I'm not keen on using this method to solve as in order for it to work it relies on first factorising T. If T is really large this will cause the solution to run in linear time (with respect to the number of digits of T) which doesn't scale to the size I want.

So what I am asking is:

Is there a way to generate integer solutions to my initial equation in logarithmic time without solving the quadratic congruence equation I showed above and without factorising T?

Answer (score 0):

Erm... sorry, but this is just a quadratic equation, and the positive solution is
$$x=\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+T}.$$ I think it's fairly easy to check if this is an integer, even for very large $T$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include variable a in the above equation here. When including a it doesn't come clear how you can solve it trivially like you mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x^{\,2}  - x = x\left( {x - 1} \right) = x^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  = 2\left( \matrix{
  x \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right) = T
$$

So first of all $T$ must be even.
Then  $$
\sqrt T  <  \approx x
$$ and for large T you can check if $$
x = \left\lceil {\sqrt T } \right\rceil 
$$
works.

In any case you can use the [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) method to find the root of $x^2-x-T=0$, and see if it is an integer.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately for some of the large values of T I have tried I don't seem to get too close to the equation evaluating near 0. I was wandering if you might know if there is some way to derive an error correcting term for this or another method in order to amend the difference from the initial approximation to the integer solution? Would it be possible to transform this into a simpler form in order to plug it into something like euclids algorithm to solve (other than direct quadratic congruence?)

Comment: Note that an integer solution **only exists for particular values of T** (now you changed into $aT$, what's the difference ?

Comment: The difference is that I do actually know the value of T beforehand - I just don't know what $a$ would be. The difference is that if the value is just T here then we can just pick any value of T to make $\sqrt{1+4T}$ evaluate to an odd number so we can get an integer value for $x$. With a fixed large T and choosable value $a$ the problem becomes more complicated to know how to solve. I think trying to make $\sqrt{1+4aT}$ evaluate as odd is a lot harder than making $\sqrt{1+a}$ evaluate as odd especially as T gets larger